# Index page for tcolorbox

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I have used tcolorbox library for my thesis, and in particular, following the documentation, I created this:

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{pabox}[2][]{%
colbacktitle=blue!30!black, colframe=blue!30!black,
title=Example ~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}
```

That I call in this way:

```
\begin{pabox}{Some title}
Some content
\end{pabox}
```

Now I want to add at the end of my thesis a page that references all the boxes I created, a sort of table of contents page but only for these boxes. Is there a way to do it programmatically?